# Reading both an image and a string in an array from text file

Tags: java, image, swing, arraylist, text-files

I'm making an image guessing game for class. What I need to do is make an arraylist that holds both the string and image path. I know there is some code out there but I'm not sure how to apply it to my game because the images aren't in a seperate class but in an array and with a string.

is there a way to do this? I have a controller for the JFrame. This class is just for the questions

```
private List<Question> myQuestions;


private int currentQuestion;

public Game() throws Exception {
    myQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

    myQuestions.add(new CharacterName("Where Image Would Go",
            "Arya Stark"));

    myQuestions.add(new CharacterName(
            "Where Image Would Go",
            "Sansa Stark"));

    myQuestions.add(new CharacterName("Where Image Would Go", "Bran Stark"));


    Collections.shuffle(myQuestions);
    currentQuestion = 1;
}
```

Comment: Okay I've made a separate class. How do I load the image to the array?

Comment: Ok, generally we don't load the image to the array, instead use a servlet to load the image wherever required.. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my understanding is correct, create a new class that holds both your String and image path

```
Class NewClass{

private String imagePath;
private String string;

//getters and setters
}
```

Now you can create an arraylist of type NewClass.

The best way to render image is to create an image servlet that can return an image on passing some kind of id or in your case the path.

```
<img src="/imageservlet/?path={imagePath}" />
```

There are lot of posts on SO and other blogs with more details on how to write your own servlet and how to return an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a class with the variables for that e.g.:

```
class Item {
   String item;
   String path;
}
```

After that you can create an ArrayList that contains them , like ArrayList< Item> 
You can also write some additional methods just to make your life easier.